# NSDate datebysettinghour always minus 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

Below is my code:-

```
-(NSDate *)getReminderDatetime
{
    NSArray *tempStrings = [self.selectedReminderInfo.reminderTime componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSInteger hour = [[tempStrings firstObject] integerValue];
    NSInteger min = [[tempStrings lastObject] integerValue];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate *reminderDate = [calendar dateBySettingHour:hour minute:min second:0 ofDate:self.selectedDate options:0];
    //reminderDate = [GeneralHelper convertToLocalTime:reminderDate];
    return reminderDate;
}
```

The result of `hour is 15` and `min is 29`. So by right, reminderDate should be `2017-06-16 15:29:00 +0000`. However, it is returning -8 hours which is `2017-06-16 09:29:00 +0000`. How can I fix it to the value I want ?

Comment: set local in dataeformatter

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I need NSDate in 24 hours format instead of NSString. Is it possible ?

Comment: Some things to consider: Is your local timezone 8 hours from UTC? Have you tried setting the timezone of `calendar`? How are you displaying the time? How does `NSLog` display a time? Work your way through those and you'll probably solve your problem. HTH